# ServiceConnect["Twitter"]

Tags: social-media

I'm trying to connect to the twitter API with the command:

```
ServiceConnect["Twitter"]
```

That's no problem if I do this at home behind my router. But when I do that at my company, it does not work and I get a URL:Fetch error.

So my question is: Do I need administrator rights because I (in this case the ServiceConnect object) need to call the browser from Mathematica?

Or is that a problem during to the firewall? I do not think it's a firewall problem because I think the call is just an HTTP or HTTPS request. The Twitter page is not blocked when I call it from the browser.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As a check: can you use Alpha from within *Mathematica* when you're using your company connection?

Comment: What's the specific error you get? You might not be able to connect to Wolfram's paclet server from which `ServiceConnect` attempts to update. If that's the case use ``Block[{$AllowInternet = False}, twitter = ServiceConnect["Twitter"]]``.

Comment: The error is: ""URLFetch::invhttp: Couldn't connect to Server". I tried Block[{$AllowInternet = False}, twitter = ServiceConnect["Twitter"]] but than I can´t use any twitter command since it Needs Internet.

Comment: ServiceConnect underneaths make call to URLFetch, Can you check what does ```URLFetch["https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"]``` returns for you(Its ok if you get error code related to bad authentication data)? Also are you seeing this with Twitter service only? Are you able to connect to say other light weight services that don't use OAuth like ServiceConnect["OpenLibrary"]?

Comment: I tried it and for URLFetch["https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"] I get the same error URLFetch::invhttp: Couldn't connect to server. If I try ServiceConnect["OpenLibrary"] Mathematica whants me to connect to the cloud (I dont have an ID right now) but it also gives back a connected ServiceObject to OpenLibrary. So OpenLibrary seems to work. I´m using Mathematica version11.0.1.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I figured it out together with the Mathematica support. If you what to connect to the internet and have a proxy that has its definition file not local but from a server within the network, you need to put in the proxy-data to Mathemtica.

Normally Mathematica gets the proxy-data directly from the local webbrowser. But if the definition is not localy stored this is not possible.

Somone can set a proxy in Mathematica with: Edit ->Preferences -> Internet & Mail -> Proxy Settings.

Hope this helps someone in the future :).